# how to omit \r\n after encoding string in base64encoding format?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, base64, nsstringencoding

I have a issue in omitting \r\n after encoding the string, below is the encoded string which I have got,

```
QzAxODBCMDQtNDdDMi00QzhDLTg1MTAtNUE1MzU1RDIzRDA4Ojk4Mzg5MzRkYzky\r\nNTRkYWE4ODljY2Q0ZGYxNjljYTU
```

Comment: Your code produced this base64-encoded string? How? Show the code. Or are you receiving this from somewhere and you need to decode it? Ideally, you'd fix the source to not do that, but in a pinch you can simply replace the literal `\r\n` with an actual newline. Use `-[NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]` or the like.

Comment: @KenThomases, Thanks for your reply, actually I getting the string as `QzAxODBCMDQtNDdDMi00QzhDLTg1MTAtNUE1MzU1RDIzRDA4Ojk4Mzg5MzRkYzky         NTRkYWE4ODljY2Q0ZGYxNjljYTU` like this after `ky` the `NTR` starts in next line. I using the NSData+base64.h & .m files to encode the string.

Comment: Why is it a problem that there's a newline? That's typical of base64 because many transmission media (like email) have a line-length limit. Anyway, if you really want to eliminate it, you can still use the method I recommended above. Replace `@"\n"` and/or `@"\r"` with `@""`.

Comment: @KenThomases, Thanks for ur reply, I have tried the above mentioned method but still no luck. As you said it is right that its shouldn't be th problem but when I am getting the response I see the encoded string `QzAxODBCMDQtNDdDMi00QzhDLTg1MTAtNUE1MzU1RDIzRDA4Ojk4Mzg5MzRkYzky\r\nNTRkYWE4ODljY2Q0ZGYxNjljYTU` like this. Also I have added it in my header (HTTPHeader while requesting the server), I don't see this header parameter but rest of the header fields when I print in the log. Any guess about this. Thanks.

Comment: You just said you're not getting a string with a literal "\r\n" it it and now you say you are getting that. Which is it? From where are you getting the string? Show code. Show verbatim log output.

Comment: @SantoshGurram You need to edit your question and post where you got your `NSData+base64.h` and `.m` files.  Be specific.  We need to look at those files to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily remove the `\r\n` from a string like this:

```
NSString *outString = [inString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r\n" withString:@""];
```

If you want to create the strings without `\r\n` in the first place, then it depends on how you create them.  For example, if you're using the Base64 category from [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html), you need to add this line before the call to `BIO_write` in `base64EncodedString`:

```
BIO_set_flags(context, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
```

He explains this in the article.

Comment: I am getting the encoded string like mentioned below                         `QzAxODBCMDQtNDdDMi00QzhDLTg1MTAtNUE1MzU1RDIzRDA4Ojk4Mzg5MzRkYzky
NTRkYWE4ODljY2Q0ZGYxNjljYTUw`                                          but I need it in one line. Please help if possible explain with a scenario.